# Marker on Click and send the marker's name/id from javascript to C# (using Mapbox gl-js)

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

from this example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster-html/
I have already made similar to this but there's something I wanted to change because of the performance issue
and it's on the setPopup. instead, I wanted to load the popup separately by removing it in the current logic. see the code below

```
new Feature{
            Type = "Features",
      
            Properties = new Properties{  Title = "Marker-1",Altitude=50.00},

            Geometry = new Geometry
            {
                Type = "Point", Coordinates = new List<double>{ 148.9819, -35.39847 }
            },


        },
    new Feature
        {

            Type = "Features",
         
            Properties = new Properties{  Title = "Marker-2",Altitude=80.00 },

            Geometry = new Geometry
            {
                Type = "Point", Coordinates = new List<double>{ 119.06535, -22.77616 }
            }


        var features = mapBox.querySourceFeatures('marker-data', {
                layers: ['unclustered-point']
            });

        for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                var coords = features[i].geometry.coordinates;
                var props = features[i].properties;

               
                if (props.cluster) continue;
                //var id = props.cluster_id;

               
                var id = features[i].properties.title;
               

                var marker = markers[id];
                if (!marker) {

                var el=   document.createElement('div');

                    el.className = props.className;
                    el.innerHTML = props.innerHTML;
                    test = props.title;
                    marker = markers[id] = new mapboxgl.Marker({
                        element: el
                    }).setLngLat(coords);//.setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML(props.title));
            
            
                   componentInstance.invokeMethodAsync("NotifyClickMarker",props.title);
                   
                }

                newMarkers[id] = marker;


                if (!markersOnScreen[id]) marker.addTo(mapBox);
            }
```

I wonder if there are any possible ways to get the details when the marker is 'click' from the map and then send the marker's name/Id from javascript to C# using invokeMethodAsync("NotifyClickMarker",props.title); so then I can use it as a parameter value to call the popup from another method. the problem is that it will not dynamically change the value when clicking the second marker.

Comment: I have resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem by adding this line of code. I got this code from another source which I think really helped. see this [Clickable Markers](https://gist.github.com/chriswhong/8977c0d4e869e9eaf06b4e9fda80f3ab)

```
 class ClickableMarker extends mapboxgl.Marker {
            // new method onClick, sets _handleClick to a function you pass in
            onClick(handleClick) {
                this._handleClick = handleClick;
                return this;
            }

            //The existing _onMapClick was there to trigger a popup
            // but we are hijacking it to run a function we define
            _onMapClick(e) {
                const targetElement = e.originalEvent.target;
                const element = this._element;

                if (this._handleClick && (targetElement === element || element.contains((targetElement)))) {
                    this._handleClick();
                }
            }
        }
```

Then also replace the code inside that function updateMarkers() by calling the ClikableMarker and then changing for-loop into forEach  for the geojson data

```
 geojonData.forEach(function (features) {

                var coords = features.geometry.coordinates;
                var props = features.properties;




                var id = features.properties.title;
                var marker = markers[id];

                if (!marker) {

                    var el = document.createElement('div');
                    el.className = props.className;
                    el.innerHTML = props.innerHTML;

                    marker = markers[id] = new ClickableMarker({ element: el })
                        .setLngLat([coords[0], coords[1]])
                        .onClick(() => {
                            console.log('Yawers', props.title);
                            componentInstance.invokeMethodAsync('NotifyOnClickMarker', props.title);
                        });
                    //.addTo(mapBox);

                }
                newMarkers[id] = marker;

                if (!markersOnScreen[id]) marker.addTo(mapBox);
            });
```

[image]